# how to index cck field of type text area in solr: drupal6

Tags: drupal-6, solr

I've created a cck filed of type **textarea** with name **filed_desc**, how do i get this field to index in solr.

i found this article http://acquia.com/blog/understanding-apachesolr-cck-api, i have tried this but it is not indexing the filed, can somebody help.

```
    <?php
// $Id$
/**
* Implementation of hook_apachesolr_cck_fields_alter
*/
function example_apachesolr_cck_fields_alter(&$mappings) {
  // either for all CCK of a given field_type and widget option
  // 'filefield' is here the CCK field_type. Correlates to $field['field_type']
  $mappings['text'] = array(
    'text_textarea' => array('callback' => 'example_callback', 'index_type' => 'string'),

  );

}



/**
* A function that gets called during indexing.
* @node The current node being indexed
* @fieldname The current field being indexed
*
* @return an array of arrays. Each inner array is a value, and must be
* keyed 'value' => $value
*/
function example_callback($node, $fieldname) {
  $fields = array();
  foreach ($node->$fieldname as $field) {
    // In this case we are indexing the filemime type. While this technically
    // makes it possible that we could search for nodes based on the mime type
    // of their file fields, the real purpose is to have facet blocks during
    // searching.
    $fields[] = array('value' => $field['field_desc']);
  }
  return $fields;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on adding this in a nice, pretty, generic way. If you really need this working now, take a look at [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/664896) on Drupal.org. My code is currently living at [GitHub](http://github.com/haxney/apachesolr), though hopefully I can get this included upstream and make a release of it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How did that go in the end? Which is the patch to use that's mentioned in the thread? And is your code going to remain a separate branch or be added back to the main apachesolr development?

Answer (score 0):

Per field mapping is easier to control.

alter function:

```
$mappings['per-field']['field_specialities'] = array(
  'index_type' => 'string',
  'callback' => 'ge_search_apachesolr_field_specialities_callback'
);
```

callback:

```
function ge_search_apachesolr_field_specialities_callback($node, $fieldname)
{
  $fields = array();
  foreach($node->$fieldname as $field) {
    $fields[] = array('value' => $field['value']);
  }
  return $fields;
}
```